# How to keep the Advice and the targetObject in the same transaction

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-transactions

Please help, how to keep the Advice and the `targetObject` in the same transaction?

I’m using spring-boot:1.4.0.RELEASE, and using `@Transactional` to control the transaction, the code as below,

```
@Transactional
public String doA() {
    insertA();
    insertB();
    insertC();
    return null;
}
```

I’m defined the Advice, and wanna keep the Advice and the doA() in the same transaction.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DoAAspect implements Ordered {
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* doA()")
    public void pointcut(){
    }
    @Around(value = "pointcut()")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint) throws Throwable {
        try {
            Object returnVal = jointPoint.proceed();
            if(true)
                throw new RuntimeException("xxxx");
            return returnVal;
        } catch (Throwable tx) {
            tx.printStackTrace();
            throw tx;
        }
    }
    public int getOrder() {
        return 0; // I’m trying to return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE or Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE
    }
}
```

I hope It can  rollback  the transaction  of `insertA()`, `insertB()`, insertC() when throw new RuntimeException(). But no matter how i’ve done, it all failed. The calling as below:
`DoAAspect.around()` -> `TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction()` -> `doA()` -> `TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction()` -> `DoAAspect.around()`
How colud keep the Advice and the `doA()` in the same transaction? Please， thx